# Testing Redux arrow function Action Creators

Tags: unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I have an arrow function in my React-Redux application that dispatches just an action without a payload, which will wipe (Reset) a part of my Redux store. There's no HTTP ([or Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564013/testing-redux-thunk-action-creator)) involved.

```js
export const resetSearch = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: RESET_SEARCH
  });
};
```

I want to test that it returns the correct Action type:

```js
import * as actions from '../actions/actionCreators';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

describe('actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to reset part of the store', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: types.RESET_SEARCH
    };
    expect(actions.resetSearch()).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

The test is not passing because I need to return an Object but, instead, I send this anonimous arrow function. Here is the Jest output

**Expected value to equal: {"type": "RESET_SEARCH"}**

**Received: [Function anonymous]**

How should the test be?
All help will be apreaciated!

Thanks

Comment: Call the returned function with an implementation of dispatch that returns the dispatch's parameter? I mean, you're not returning an object, you're returning a function. I'm not sure *why*, but that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you plese try below code snippet, It should do:

```
const expectedAction = {
  type: types.RESET_SEARCH
};

let retnFunc = actions.resetSearch();
retnFunc((receivedAction)=>{
    expect(receivedAction).toEqual(expectedAction);  
});
```

Here **resetSearch** returns a function which gets called with the action object so just imitated the same.

Let me know if you need any more help!